# react-navigation/bottom-tabs render a white page

Tags: react-native, expo

I have this component :

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

const bottomTabOptions = ({ route }) => {
  // getting the route object
  const item = routes.find((routeItem) => routeItem.name === route.name)

  if (!item) {
    console.error(`Route ${route.name} not found in routes array.`)
    return {}
  }

  const commonStyle = {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lightGrey,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    paddingTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10
  }

  if (!item.showInTab) {
    return {
      tabBarButton: () => <View style={{ width: 0 }} />,
      headerShown: false,
      tabBarStyle: commonStyle,
      title: item.title
    }
  }

  return {
    title: item.title,
    tabBarStyle: commonStyle,
    headerShown: false,
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => item.icon(focused)
  }
}

const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={bottomTabOptions}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="HomeNavigator"
        component={HomeNavigator}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

And this part of code render a white page when building using eas. I'm using expo.

Any idea on how to fix it ? Already remove all code that could be related to this error.

And every time I change some code, I need to rebuild all and try it on a real device, in simulator, all work fine.